# How can I detect if the page is at the top?

Tags: javascript, events, scroll

I want to make an event occur when the page scroll is at the top of the page.
Also I need an `if` statement for it.
I am a beginner with javascript so any help is appreciated.

I am looking for something like this:

```
if (at_the_top_of_the_page) {
do_the_event_here
}
```

I think this is the right struckture for it. But I don't know what is the right code. I know that it will be in javascript. But I really don't know how...

Answer (score 9):

Elements have a `scrollTop` element that can be read or set. Make sure you're reading the correct element's scrollTop, the one that you're scrolling.

ex:

```
var div = document.getElementById('scrollable');
if(div.scrollTop==0){
    //Top of element
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the position of the scrollbar using this

```
function Getpostion(){    
    var vscroll = document.body.scrollTop;    
    alert(vscroll);
}
```

if vscroll is zero do your job. [More details](http://www.softcomplex.com/docs/get_window_size_and_scrollbar_position.html)

Comment: I have edited it for ie  because in ie 'var vscroll = (document.all ? document.scrollTop : window.pageYOffset);' was undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
document.body.scrollTop === 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

To do the easy way:
Include jquery library in your HTML document.

And to check if the user is on top of the page

```
var scrollPosition = $("body, html").scrollTop()
if (scrollPosition == 0){
   // top of the page
}
```

Comment: It would solve a lot of problems if people learned Javascript before they learned jQuery.

Comment: Well you have a point. But when it comes to quick way of doing things and not worry abt browser compatibility, jQuery is the best

Comment: @Walkerneo I would agree generally, but keep in mind that some of the earlier IEs' implementations of `document.body.scrollTop` are problematic (IIRC it always reports `0` in some HTML4 doctypes). When dealing with `scrollTop`, jQuery requests the y-offset in several ways (e.g. http://goo.gl/Hn7lo).

Answer (score -22):

You would have to use javascript. Get to learn a little bit of [jQuery](http://www.nomadjourney.com/2009/09/go-to-top-of-page-using-jquery/).

Comment: As he's said, he knows it's supposed to be in JavaScript.

Comment: Some meat around the bones would be helpful instead of one liners about which language to use.